# Form and other Buttons won't display inline

Tags: html, css

How do I get the prev and next button to be on the same line as the form select elements? I tried using `display:inline` but it does not work.

```css
button {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=August&year=2014'">Prev</button>
<form action="index?view=list" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" style="margin:20px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="list" />
    <select name="month" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="January" >January</option>
        <option value="February" >February</option>
        <option value="March" >March</option>
        <option value="April" >April</option>
        <option value="May" >May</option>
        <option value="June" >June</option>
        <option value="July" >July</option>
        <option value="August" >August</option>
        <option value="September" Selected>September</option>
        <option value="October" >October</option>
        <option value="November" >November</option>
        <option value="December" >December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" onchange="this.form.submit();">
     <option value="2014" selected>2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option>    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=October&year=2014'">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<form>` nodes have a block style to them.  Change the display to `inline-block` to fix this.

```css
form {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=August&year=2014'">Prev</button>
<form action="index?view=list" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" style="margin:20px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="list" />
    <select name="month" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="January" >January</option>
        <option value="February" >February</option>
        <option value="March" >March</option>
        <option value="April" >April</option>
        <option value="May" >May</option>
        <option value="June" >June</option>
        <option value="July" >July</option>
        <option value="August" >August</option>
        <option value="September" Selected>September</option>
        <option value="October" >October</option>
        <option value="November" >November</option>
        <option value="December" >December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" onchange="this.form.submit();">
     <option value="2014" selected>2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option>    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=October&year=2014'">Next</button>
```

Comment: yep I was going to say this. Basically it needs to be on FORM not on BUTTON.

Answer (score 4):

```css
button,
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=August&year=2014'">Prev</button>
<form action="index?view=list" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" style="margin:20px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="view" value="list" />
  <select name="month" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September" Selected>September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
  </select>
  <select name="year" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="2014" selected>2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button onclick="location.href='?view=list&month=October&year=2014'">Next</button>
```

Comment: yep I was going to say this. Basically it needs to be on FORM not on BUTTON.